# Can X x(t...) ever result in a function declaration with vexing parse?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I was writing a function template as

```
template<typename ...T>
void f(T ...t) {
  X x(t...);
  // ...
}
```

When I was looking at it, I was wondering what happens for a call `f()`. Will vexing  parse make x a function declaration? Compilers seem to make it a variable. Can someone help me be sure about it please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The empty parenthesis (`()`) will make it a function declaration only if it's written as such in the source code.

`§14.5.3 [temp.variadic] p6` also mentions this:

> The instantiation of a pack expansion that is not a sizeof... expression produces a list E1, E2, ..., EN, where N is the number of elements in the pack expansion parameters. [...] When N is zero, the instantiation of the expansion produces an empty list. **Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic interpretation of the enclosing construct**, even in cases where omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed or would result in an ambiguity in the grammar. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class... T> struct X : T... { };
> template<class... T> void f(T... values) {
> X<T...> x(values...);
> }
> template void f<>(); // OK: X<> has no base classes
>                      // x is a variable of type X<> that is value-initialized
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

See specifically the second comment in the example code.